# Criterion for $a^i=a^j$ proof

Tags: group-theory, finite-groups

Let G be a group and let a be an element in G. If a has infinite order, then $$a^i=a^j$$ if and only if $i=j$
If $a$ has finite order, say $n$, then 
$$\left \langle a \right \rangle=\{e,a,a^2,...,a^n-1\}$$

and $$a^i=a^j$$ if and only if $n$ divides $i-j$.

The first part of the proof says:
If a has infinite order, then $$a^i=a^j$$ if and only if $i=j$.

I have managed to show the "only IF" part. How do I show the "IF" part? I know that if $$i=j$$ then $$a^i=a^j$$ but how do I show?

Also, as to the second part of the proof, there is an ambiguity I'd like to clarify:

Are they saying 
"If $A \implies$ $($B$ and $C$) \iff D$ or "If ($A \implies B$), and ($C \iff D$)?

Comment: The "if" part is trivial: if $i = j$, then $a^i = a^j$, because $i$ and $j$ are literally the same integer.

Comment: I have shown it in the comment section of the answer below. 
I multiplied both sides by an integer, a. This is followed by raising them to the i and j exponent. Please have a look.

Comment: I'm not sure you follow what I'm saying. If we take $a^{\text{something}}$ and we say $\text{something} = \text{another thing}$ (they are EQUAL, the SAME), then $a^{\text{something}} = a^{\text{another thing}}$, for surely $a^i = a^i$.

Comment: I do understand although I may have overthink this at the outset.
I arrive at the same conclusion as yours, using a slight different train of thought.
I multiplied both sides by the same integer and using the standard operation( I.e., $$1.n=1^n$$)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hint: If $a$ has infinite order and $a^{i}=a^{j}$ then $(a^{i})^{-1}=a^{-i}$.  Multiply $a^{i}$ and $a^{j}$ by $a^{-i}$ and see what happens...

EDIT: extra hint... you'll see that $a^{j-i}=e$ and $j\neq i$ so $j-i\neq 0$... what does it mean to have infinite order?

To clarify the ambiguity:  The statement is "Let $a$ be an element of finite order $n$.  Then $a^{i}=a^{j}$ if and only if $n|(i-j)$."  You show $A\Rightarrow B$ and $B\Rightarrow A$ where $A$ is "$a^{i}=a^{j}$" and $B$ is "$n|(i-j)$."

The IF direction would be $A\Rightarrow B$, or IF $a^{i}=a^{j}$ THEN $n|(i-j)$.

Comment: @user, If this doesn't give you enough direction (or clarify the misunderstanding) let me know and I'll try to explain better.

Comment: To show the "IF" part:

Let $$i=j$$
$$ai=aj \implies a^i=a^j$$?

To have an infinite order, it means there exists no smallest positive integer, n, such that $$a^n=e$$

Comment: @user, If $i=j$ it is easy because the power is the same.  If $i\neq j$ (and $a^{i}=a^{j}$) then $e=a^{-i}a^{i}=a^{-i}a^{j}=a^{j-i}$.  Note that since $j\neq i$ it follows that $j-i\neq 0$.  Then $e=a^{j-i}$ so clearly $a$ does not have infinite order.

Comment: @user, in the infinite order case, there is really nothing to show for the IF direction (because $i=j$).

Comment: I will give the the your clarification some thoughts.
Yes, the "IF" part was trivial. And thanks for providing a tangent as to what if "i is not equivalent to j".